# Visual web part first time connection to CRM are wery slowly

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint-2010, web-parts, dynamics-crm-2011

I have sharepoint 2010 solution with 3 web parts, which connects to Microsoft Dynamics CRM, when I open one of three web parts on first time, they are very slow in being connect to CRM, after the first load everything works pretty quickly.

which could be the problem and what could be a solution to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use fiddler to verify, but it sounds like this is related to the initial login/handshake.